# PHP curl Issues with fopen vs $_FILES["photo_file"]["tmp_name"]

Tags: php, arrays, file, curl, fopen

I had a working relationship with a Java server and a PHP server using curl from php.

Using curl I sent over an array with image data and some string vaules.

In PHP, the image was taken directly (tmp storage) from a HTTP POST form and put in the array, successfully. But now I need to `move_uploaded_file` first to a specified directory and read it back with fopen into another PHP document that use curl.

The only difference is that I used $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], and now I use fopen. Code:

```
// $image = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]; Had success with this one from FORM POST
// $filename = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

$filename = $_POST["filename"]; // file name from ajax post

$image = fopen('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\app\\uploads\\'.$filename, "rw"); // the sinner?

$data = array(
    'uploaded_file' => '@' . $image . ';filename=' . $filename,
);
....
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // the Java web service URI
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($c);
```

Error:

```
Erreur curl : couldn't open file "Resource id #3" 
Array
(
     [uploaded_file] => @Resource id #3;filename=480x_13197743.jpg
)
```

**EDIT:**

I printed the array from the working solution, and it points to the file/resource differently:

```
Array
(
    [uploaded_file] => @C:\xampp\tmp\php20EA.tmp;filename=magn.png
)
```

Or better said, it has just a file path string. Ok, so that fixed it, using just the file path, and disregarding any copy of binary data. Answered my question =|

Comment: Did you know that after php script execution file $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"] will be deleted. You must move it to other location.

Comment: What do you want to put in the array? A filename? Or the file itself (in some encoded format)? With `fopen` you get a handle back.

Comment: Thats what I said with `move_uploaded_file`. I wonder if there is some difference in file encoding or something that isnt suitable to use with an array, clueless atm.

Comment: @initall, the file content itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the "Uploading file" example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Simply specify the file path in your array, not a resource handle `fopen` returns.